# Restricting program access in OpenBSD

Tags: ssh, svn, openbsd

I'm hosting a svn+ssh repo on a OpenBSD box and wondered if it is possible to deny access to any other programs despite svnserve? The reason is that I want to restrict access to parts of the repo with path-based authentication, but having access to arbitrary shell commands defies the use of this as someone could just download the whole db.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into restricting the programs ran via ssh. The following shows you how to do so when using keys for authentication . I am sure with a little more looking into the man pages it can be done when using password for auth as well.

http://troy.jdmz.net/rsync/index.html